# Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с массивом

Tags: php

Получаю через youtube api ключевые слова к ролику
Получилось вывести массив в виде ключевых слов через запятую

```
    <?php
$my_array=join(", ",Main::tags());
print_r($my_array); 
echo Main::tags(); //выводит данные из конфига если нет ключей
?>
```

Сейчас работает, если ключи с ютуба получены они отображаются а в конце добавляется Array + ошибка
Notice: Array to string conversion in в строке echo Main::tags();

Если ключи с ютуба не получены, значение заданное в конфиге отображается корректно но тоже есть ошибка
Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in в строке $my_array=join(", ",Main::tags());

Помогите вписать значение из конфига в мою конструкцию, верно.
Т.е., чтобы если с ютуба ключи не получены, вывелось значение tags из конфига
Спасибо!

Comment: Где у Вас ключи из ютуба и из конфига?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример что возвращает вызов Main::tags() в обоих случаях

Comment: echo Main::tags(); tags в конфеге у меня отвечает за вывод дефолтных слов и tags с ютуба парсит ключи. За счет join Main::tags(); возвращает ключи через запятую с ютуба но если на ютубе нет ключей, должно подменять на дефолтные из конфига echo Main::tags();

Comment: `public static function tags(){
if(empty(self::$tags)){
return self::$config["tags"];
}else{
return self::$tags;
}
}`

Comment: Вывел ключи так:
Цитата:
`<?php
$my_array=join(", ",Main::tags());
print_r($my_array);
?>`
Теперь если ключи есть то они выводятся.

Но если ключей нет то код
Цитата:
`public static function tags(){
if(empty(self::$tags)){
return self::$config["tags"];
}else{
return self::$tags;
}
}`
не работает и заданные в админке ключи не отображаются.
При этом возникают ошибки:

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$tags in 
Main::set("tags",$yt->snippet->tags);
и
Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in 
$my_array=join(", ",Main::tags());